# Is there a way to handle HTTP responses in WCF when exceptions occur?

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services

I have a web service that looks something like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public class MyService
{
   [OperationContract]
   public void BreakStuff()
   {
      throw new MyException();
   }
}
```

It's not a very powerful web service right now, but you watch - it's gonna be great!

If I call `BreakStuff()`, WCF traps the exception, returns an HTTP 500 and optionally spits out a serialized stack trace if `IncludeExceptionDetailsInFaults` is set to true.  I'd like to override this behavior and spit out my own custom error message object, and return HTTP 200.  I want to do this because I think throwing exceptions in certain cases is *cleaner* than littering the code with *try/catch* blocks and having all web methods return some sort of *Result* object.

What I've done is implemented my own `IDispatchMessageFormatter`, which has the contract:

```
public interface IDispatchMessageFormatter
{
   void DeserializeRequest(Message message, object[] parameters);
   Message SerializeReply(MessageVersion messageVersion, object[] parameters, object result);
}
```

`SerializeReply` gets called for normal HTTP 200 responses, however if the web method throws an exception, WCF never calls `SerializeReply` so I'm not given the chance to control the response output.

Does WCF provide the ability to customize error responses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement a custom error handler by implementing the [IErrorHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.aspx) interface. I've used this approach in the past to return custom error information in JSON format. In the [ProvideFault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.providefault.aspx) method you can also change the response code. Below is a sample of one approach I've used.

```
public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
{   
    fault = GetJsonResponseFromException(version, error);
    ConfigureMessageFormat(ref fault);
    ConfigureHttpReponse(ref fault, error);
}

protected virtual void ConfigureMessageFormat(ref Message fault)
{
    var formatting =
      new WebBodyFormatMessageProperty(WebContentFormat.Json);
    fault.Properties.Add(WebBodyFormatMessageProperty.Name, formatting);
}

protected virtual void ConfigureHttpReponse(ref Message fault, Exception error)
{
    var exception = error as WebFaultException<ServiceFault>;
    var statusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
    var description = HttpWorkerRequest
        .GetStatusDescription(Convert.ToInt32(statusCode));

    if (exception != null)
    {
        statusCode = exception.StatusCode;
        description = exception.Reason.Translations[0].Text;
    }

    var httpResponse = new HttpResponseMessageProperty()
    {
        StatusCode = statusCode,
        StatusDescription = description
    };

    httpResponse.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
    fault.Properties.Add(HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name, httpResponse);
}
```